# Understanding the snapshot_jobid in syspublications and its job association

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have successfully set up a SQL Server transactional replication topology and it's functioning as intended. While exploring the publication properties, I noticed the snapshot_jobid column in the syspublications system table. However, I'm unable to locate a corresponding job on either the publisher or distributor instance using this ID. This leads me to the following questions:

1. What is this snapshot_jobid column in syspublications?
2. Where is the corresponding job associated with this ID located?

I'd appreciate any insights or explanations related to this matter.

For reference, the documentation states that snapshot_jobid represents the "scheduled task ID". However, this information isn't sufficient to understand its actual functionality and location.

Any assistance in clarifying this topic would be greatly appreciated!